# Converting into PostgreSQL Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I convert the below line into PostgreSQL?

```
WHERE c."timestamp" >= DATE_ADD('day', -30, 
CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/New_York', SYSDATE))
```

I tried this

```
WHERE c."timestamp" >= date_trunc('day', -30, TIMEZONE('America/New_York', localtimestamp))
```

and getting this error:

ERROR:  function date_trunc(unknown, integer, timestamp with time zone) does not exist
LINE 20: WHERE c."timestamp" >= date_trunc('day', -30,

Also not sure, If I am doing it correctly or not.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

Comment: You would do some research potentially via the official documentation and find the equivalent.

Comment: WHERE c."timestamp" >= date_part('day', -30, 
TIMEZONE('America/New_York', localtimestamp)) tried this, but still getting an error on date_part.

Comment: also tried date_trunc instead of date_part.

Comment: Hey Dale k, I did some research,  tried different things, and then posted here when I failed to solve this.

Comment: @AnsaDhedhi: Show us what you tried and what (error) messages you got.

Comment: I have updated the Question. Kindly check.

Answer (score 1):

Under most circumstances, I would expect this to be sufficient:

```
where c.timestamp > current_date - interval '30 day'
```

However, the exact translation is:

```
where c.timestamp > (current_timestamp at time zone 'America/New_York' - interval '30 day')
```

Note that when using a larger number of days, the time component is not relevant.  And timezones may or may not be useful in your actually application, which is why the first solution may be a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Interval key word like CurrentDate + INTERVAL '1 day'. Following link is FYI,

https://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/dateadd

Comment: Hey Aizaz, Thanks for replying. 
tried this : ```WHERE c."timestamp" >= current_date + INTERVAL 'day' -30
TIMEZONE('America/New_York', localtimestamp)) ``` still not working.

Comment: Try this: select current_date - INTERVAL '30 day';
+ You need to subtract the date instead of adding